# Error fetch network request failed with react-native

Tags: react-native, fetch

I am a beginner with fetch and trying to get some data from JSON-server to my react native app but it gave me the same error always... "network request failed"
I tried to use Ip instead of localhost like "http://192.168.x.x:3000" but nothing changed and my expo is 192.168.x.x:19000. what I forgot to do? and why this error always happened?

```
export const fetchDishes = () => (dispatch) => {
dispatch(dishesLoading());

return fetch("http://192.168.1.5:3000/dishes")
.then(
  (response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response;
    } else {
      var error = new Error(
        "Error " + response.status + ": " + response.statusText
      );
      error.respone = response;
      throw error;
    }
  },
  (error) => {
    var errmss = new Error(error.message);
    throw errmss;
  }
)
.then((respone) => respone.json())
.then((dishes) => dispatch(addDishes(dishes)))
.catch((error) => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)));
};
```

[My Expo screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOYbD.png)

Comment: you should post some code for clarifying your question

Comment: if you have your routes set up correctly it should work. do you get data back testing it in the browser? and what are u using emulator or device?

Comment: I updated the question, I hope I gave the necessary code to clarify my problem. @H.sanati

Comment: I don't use routes and I don't know how I make a test in my browser. I am a beginner and I don't understand fetching data from the server well yet. I updated the question and put a screen of my expo, I think it is an emulator, not a device. @yesIamFaded

Comment: use postman for testing your api response

Comment: I made the test with postman and it works fine when using http://localhost:3000/dishes but when using IP it didn't work, what that means? @H.sanati

Comment: I finally solved the problem, I used this command... json-server --host 192.168.1.XX db.json. Thank you both for trying to help :)